# Multiple running SparkContexts detected in the same JVM - Java Spark

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to use a `JavaSparkContext` to read from a `MongoDB` collection. So I have the following utility:

```
public class SparkUtil {

    private String host;

    private Integer port;

    private String database;

    public final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( SparkUtil.class );

    private static final String SPARK_MONGO_INPUT_URI = "spark.mongodb.input.uri";
    private static final String SPARK_MONGO_OUTPUT_URI = "spark.mongodb.output.uri";

    private static SparkConf conf;
    private static JavaSparkContext jsc;


    /**
     * 
     * @param master
     * @param appname
     * @param inputCollection
     * @param outputCollection
     */
    public SparkUtil(final String host, final Integer port, final String database,
                     final String master, final String appname, final String inputCollection,
                     final String outputCollection) {
        try {
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
            this.database = database;
            String inputURI = this.formatMongoURI(inputCollection);
            String outputURI = this.formatMongoURI(outputCollection);
            log.info("----------------------------------------------------");
            log.info("Mongo Input URI: " + inputURI);
            log.info("Mongo Output URI: " + outputURI);
            log.info("----------------------------------------------------");
            conf = new SparkConf()
                            .setMaster(master)
                            .setAppName(appname)
                            .set(SPARK_MONGO_INPUT_URI, inputURI)
                            .set(SPARK_MONGO_OUTPUT_URI, outputURI)
                            .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
            SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
            jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sc);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
16:19:58.929 [main] DEBUG org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED @36813ms o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@de81be1{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16:19:58.931 [main] WARN org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Multiple running SparkContexts detected in the same JVM!
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:77)
cloudos.utils.SparkUtil.<init>(SparkUtil.java:65)
utils.SparkUtilTest.setUp(SparkUtilTest.java:47)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:2223)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$2.apply(SparkContext.scala:2219)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.assertNoOtherContextIsRunning(SparkContext.scala:2219)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.setActiveContext(SparkContext.scala:2305)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:2175)
    at cloudos.utils.SparkUtil.<init>(SparkUtil.java:65)
    at utils.SparkUtilTest.setUp(SparkUtilTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:81)
    at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:69)
    at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:689)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1014)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:720)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
16:19:58.932 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@1fa121e2 testClass = SparkUtilTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class utils.SparkUtilTest$ContextConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{classpath:test.properties}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@6aba2b86, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@47af7f3d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
16:19:58.932 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@4b7dc788 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 12, missCount = 1]
```

I'm running that from the following `Unit Test`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class SparkUtilTest {

    public final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( SparkUtilTest.class );

    private SparkUtil sparkUtil;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Configuration
    @TestPropertySource(value="classpath:test.properties")
    static class ContextConfiguration {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.sparkUtil = new SparkUtil(this.host, this.port, this.database, "local", 
                                       "AmazonML", "aws_instances",  "aws_instances");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMethods() {
        assertNotNull(this.sparkUtil.getJavaSparkContext());
        assertNotNull(this.sparkUtil.getSparkConfig());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRead() {
        JavaRDD<Document> rdd = this.sparkUtil.read();
        assertNotNull(rdd);
        assertNotEquals(rdd.count(), 0);
        log.info("-------------------------------------");
        log.info("Count: " + rdd.count());
        log.info("Object: " + rdd.first().toJson());
        log.info("-------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

I have made use of `set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")` but it doesn't make any difference.
I'm using `scala 2.12`, `mongo-spark-connector_2.11`, `spark-sql_2.11` and `Spark 1.63`. How can I fix my issue?

Comment: Supporting multiple contexts in the same JVM is not supported - see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243 - So either sharing a context across your tests will fix it or stopping and starting one for each test will but that is really slow, so I'd recommend you share one.

Also, just to note you can't use Scala 2.12 with Scala 2.11 compiled code as its not binary compatible. So you may want to correct your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is caused by your `setUp()` method, which is annotated with `@Before`, so it is called before each `@Test`. In this case it is called twice because you have two tests, and this is why there are two SparkContexts created.

The simplest solution seems to be replacing `@Before` with `@BeforeClass`, but this will only solve the problem temporarily (until you add more classes with tests). However, you can try this now to see if it helps at all.

You could also try `stop`ping the `SparkContext` after each test (using `@After` or `@AfterClass` if you changed `@Before` to `@BeforeClass`). I think you should `stop` it when it's no longer needed anyway, as a good practice.

Another solution would be to make sure that `SparkUtil` is created only once per JVM. You could simply use the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but then you would have no easy way of stopping `SparkContext`. Maybe Spring Boot provides a better mechanism for initialisation and clean up?